# Could not load file or assembly 'System.WindowsBrowser' in WinForms project

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, .net-assembly, lync-2013

I'd be thankful if anyone could help me.

I have a simple WinForms project, which performs LogIn to Microsoft Lync 2013 by code.
On runtime, I got the following Error:

> **Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Browser, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

Since I don't have this System.Windows.Browser reference at all, 
I've operated **Fusion Log Viewer** in order to find out who's the problematic reference, and found row says:

> **The operation failed. Calling assembly : Microsoft.Lync.Utilities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.**

The next rows in that log mentioned attemptions to download different browser dlls,
for example:

> **Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/Proj/TestProjects/LyncLogInProject/LyncLogIn/bin/Debug/System.Windows.Browser.DLL.**

So.....
Why does my winforms applications try to contact any browser?
Which of references causes the problem - System.Windows.Browser or Microsoft.Lync.Utilities?
and how can I finally solve this failure?

I'll mention that my reference is declared as CopyLocal=True,
and that I've already tryed to delete bin's dlls and restart the program.
Nothing helped me so far :(

Comment: can you share the code of web.config inside the tag <dependentAssembly>

Comment: Maybe you're using the Microsoft.Lync.Utilities.dll for Silverlight rather than Desktop?

Comment: I suspect that [this helps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj933224.aspx).  If not then you'll probably have to dig through the SDK for assemblies.

Comment: Hey @amitdayama . I don't have web.config file since it is a winforms application.. Only app.config file.

Comment: @Yoink .. Maybe you're right, I didn't know two kinds of same reference are exists. How can I know which one of them I use?

Comment: Hi @HansPassant.. I've read the article but didn't find any solution. Can you please give me any specific path to find the assembly you've mentioned?